# Two JSON data merging and ECHO with PHP

Tags: php, json, merge, decode, jsondecoder

> **What is the difference from the previous questions?**
>
> In other questions, the numbers of both JSON data were equal. This
>   question does not equal JSON files.

I have two JSON data. One of them contains only 2 values. The other one contains six values. I'm trying to distinguish with IF ELSE, but two of each value is written.
In line with the numbers in the first JSON, I want to separate the second JSON data.

*For example:*

```
3 -> val3
5->  val5
```

**First JSON:**

`{"0":"3","1":"5"}`

**Second JSON:**

`{"val1":"ValueOne","val2":"ValueSecond","val3":"ValueThree","val4":"4","val5":"ValueFive","val6":"ValueSix"}`

```
$first = json_decode($jsonFile1);
$second = json_decode($jsonFile2);

foreach ($first as $key => $firstvalue) {
  foreach ($second as $secondvalue) {
    if (substr($firstvalue, -1) == $secondvalue) {  <-- 'valX' => 1
       echo "<strong>". $firstvalue . "</strong><br>";
    } else { 
       echo "<em>". $firstvalue . "</em>";
    } 
  }
}
```

Result:

---

- *ValueOne*
- *ValueOne*
- *ValueSecond*
- *ValueSecond*
- **ValueThree**
- **ValueThree**
- *ValueFour*
- *ValueFour*
- **ValueFive**
- **ValueFive**
- *ValueSix*
- *ValueSix*

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you get the output you say you are, but the repeat is due to looping each item for every item in the second array - hence each option is in there twice.

This version uses `in_array()` to see if the last character of the key is in the second JSON list (note that this is converted to an array and not objects using `true` as the second parameter of `json_decode()`)...

```
$jsonFile1 = '{"val1":"ValueOne","val2":"ValueSecond","val3":"ValueThree","val4":"4","val5":"ValueFive","val6":"ValueSix"}';
$jsonFile2 = '{"0":"3","1":"5"}';
$first = json_decode($jsonFile1);
$second = json_decode($jsonFile2, true);

foreach ($first as $key => $firstvalue) {
    if (in_array(substr($key, -1),$second)) {
        echo "<strong>". $firstvalue . "</strong><br>";
    } else {
        echo "<em>". $firstvalue . "</em><br>";
    }
}
```

gives...

*ValueOne*
*ValueSecond*
**ValueThree**
*4*
**ValueFive**
*ValueSix*

Comment: You're a man! You're a wonderful person! :) Thank you man, also; shuffle possible in case? @Nigel Ren